# Adding Grunt JavaScript watch task to a Grunt currently only watching CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, gruntjs

I setup my Grunt with the `--coffee` extension so that it would watch and compile `.coffee` files.  Problem is, I also want to add support for Grunt to watch normal `.js` files.

I tried going through my Gruntfile and finding all instances of `.coffee`, and duplicating them logically with `.js`, but after I saved and tried to run the `grunt` command, I got a **"Warning: Warning: Task "js" not found. Use --force to continue"** error.

So it doesn't seem I added the watch task properly.  Is there a command line shortcut I can use to add such a task?

Gruntfile link: https://gist.github.com/zelliott/5e59818f2babea3d7488

Comment: Please provide an extract of your Gruntfile and your directory structure.

Comment: It sounds like you accidentally replaced the `coffee` task name with `js`. So Grunt is trying to load a non-existent `js` task.

Comment: Hey guys, posted my Gruntfile via Gist.

Comment: Remove the `js` blocks you added; it's nonsense to grunt.

Also, what do you want the watched file modification to trigger? Tests? Coffeescript compilation?

Comment: So currently, the gruntfile is compiling `.coffee` files into a **combined-scripts.js** file.  I'd like it to also compile `.js` files